# Async Task reset the List to null when using runOnUiThread

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

```
    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(String... urls) {

        JPOSeReprintPreview.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                myReceipt reprintReceipt = new myReceipt ();
                lstOutput= reprintReceipt.saveReprint(muncID);

                if(lstOutput.size()==0 || lstOutput==null){
                    System.out.println("Failed Sending data");
                }
            }
        });
        return lstOutput;
    }


 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> response) {
                if(response.get(0).equals("SUCCESS")){  }  }
```

> My list lstOutput Reset to null when accessing the onPostExecute.. im having invalid index exception  at my onPostExecute.. why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You post the `Runnable` to `UI Thread` in `doInBackground()` which results in pointless `AsyncTask`.
- `lstOutput` is retuned before it is updated so it is always null.
- `if (lstOutput.size() == 0 || lstOutput == null)` will crash if it's null when calling `size()`. Should check for null in first place.

The intention of your code is unclear, but you should probably do it like

```
private final  myReceipt reprintReceipt;

public AsyncTaskName() {
    myReceipt reprintReceipt = new myReceipt();
}

@Override
protected List<String> doInBackground(String... urls) {
    return reprintReceipt.saveReprint(muncID);
}


@Override 
protected void onPostExecute(List<String> response) {
    if (response == null || response.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("Failed Sending data");
        return;
    }

    if(response.get(0).equals("SUCCESS")){
    }
}
```

Edit: if the `Handler` is created in `myReceipt()` constructor, move it's creation to `onPreExecute()` or `AsyncTask`s constructor if it's called from UI thread.
Anyway, myReceipt.saveReprint() method shouldn't use a `Handler` if it's executed in AsyncTask, so there's something totally wrong with your design.

Comment: im using an service handler to my reprintReceipt.saveReprint(muncID); that's why i added the JPOSeReprintPreview.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()... i cant use that approach it gives error at runtime (Can't create handler inside a Thread)